# Javascript function is overwritting all of my results when returning them to a class

Tags: javascript, html

I have created a javascript function to randomize 6 results from a json file of 72 entries and I'm trying to return them to a class. However, it's only returning one result. I was wondering if someone could help me return a string to a class? Or to display the results one after another.

Here is my javascript

```
<script>
function getitems() {
    var arr = [];
        for (var i = 0, l = 6; i < l; i++) {
            arr.push(Math.floor((Math.random()*72)+1))
        }
    $.getJSON('items.json',function(data) {
        for ( var i = 0; i < 6; i++ ) {
            var items = data.result.items[arr[i]].item.toString();
            $('.item-name').html(items);
        }
    }).error(function(){
    });
}
    $('#refreshItem').click(function() { 
    getitems();

});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use

```
$('.item-name').append(items);
```

in place of:

```
$('.item-name').html(items);
```

Comment: How would I then get it so that on the button click it replaces the class with new results instead of constantly adding?

Comment: On button click add below code: $('.item-name').empty(); followed by code to add new results: $('.item-name').html(items);

Answer (score 0):

This block of code is just stuffing item after item into the same set of HTML elements with this line `$('.item-name').html(items);`:

```
    for ( var i = 0; i < 6; i++ ) {
        var items = data.result.items[arr[i]].item.toString();
        $('.item-name').html(items);
    }
```

So, you will only end up with `arr[5]` in all `$('.item-name')` elements.

It is unclear exactly what you want the result to be.  Please describe further what you are trying to accomplish.

---

If you're trying to select six random result out of everything that is returned, and put them into each of six items with `class="item-name"` that already exist, then you would do that like this:

```
function getitems() {
    var arr = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
        arr.push(Math.floor((Math.random()*72)+1));
    }
    $.getJSON('items.json',function(data) {
        var items = $('.item-name');
        for ( var i = 0; i < 6; i++ ) {
            var result = data.result.items[arr[i]].item.toString();
            items.eq(i).html(result);
        }
    }).error(function(){
    });
}
```

Note, this won't guarantee that each of the six random results is different.  You might have the same result repeated.  I'm also not sure why you are adding `1` to the random result because I would assume that data.result.items is a zero-based array so you would want to include the `0` index too.

---

If you wanted to also make sure each random result was unique, you could do that like this:

```
function getitems() {
    var arr = [], used = {}, val;
    for (var i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
        do {
            val = Math.floor((Math.random()*72)+1);
        } while (!(val in used));
        used[val] = true;
        arr.push(val);
    }
    $.getJSON('items.json',function(data) {
        var items = $('.item-name');
        for ( var i = 0; i < 6; i++ ) {
            var result = data.result.items[arr[i]].item.toString();
            items.eq(i).html(result);
        }
    }).error(function(){
    });
}
```

Comment: @user2933987 - do you understand that here on StackOverflow, you should indicate to the community which answers were helpful?  This both rewards the people providing the helpful answers (with points) and rewards you for following the proper procedure. The two ways you reward helpful answers are: Pick the most helpful answer and select the checkmark to the left of the answer and upvote it by clicking the up arrow to the left of the answer.  Upvote any other helpful answers.  You will always be able to select the checkmark.  Upvoting probably requires that you earn some reputation points first.